# to_date function error in pgsql

Tags: postgresql

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW view_wf_task_log (id, taskid, ref_slip_code, toworkflownodename, fromworkflownodename, operator, operationdesc, operatedate, entertime, timeconsuming2, remark) AS SELECT 
      l.id ,
      t.id as taskId,
      t.ref_slip_code,
      node.name as toWorkFlowNodeName,
      fromnode.name as fromWorkFlowNodeName,
      us.login_name as operator,
      tran.name as operationDesc,
      l.transition_time as operateDate,
      l.enter_time as enterTime,
      (trunc(to_date(TO_CHAR(l.transition_time , 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss'),'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss') - to_date(TO_CHAR(l.enter_time , 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss'),'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss'))
            ||'day'||to_char( to_date(trunc(((to_date(TO_CHAR(l.transition_time , 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss'),'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss') - to_date(TO_CHAR(l.enter_time , 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss'),'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss'))-trunc(to_date(TO_CHAR(l.transition_time , 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss'),'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss') - to_date(TO_CHAR(l.enter_time , 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss'),'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss')))*86400),'SSSSS'),
            'fmhh24" hours "mi" min "ss" second "')) as timeConsuming2,
      l.memo as remark
  FROM   WF_WORKFLOW_TASK_LOG l
    inner join WF_WORKFLOW_TASK t on(l.task_id=t.id)
    left join T_AU_USER us on(l.user_id=us.id)
    inner join WF_WORKFLOW_NODE node on(l.to_node_no=node.node_no )
    left join WF_WORKFLOW_NODE fromnode on(l.from_node_no=fromnode.node_no )
    left join WF_WORKFLOW_TRANSITION tran on(l.transition_code=tran.code and fromnode.id=tran.from_node_id   and  tran.to_node_id=node.id)
 where
       node.workflow_id=t.workflow_id      and ( fromnode.workflow_id=t.workflow_id      or  coalesce(fromnode.workflow_id::text, '') = '')
       and l.transition_time>=l.enter_time
;
```

when I executed the above code,got the error.

```
[Err] ERROR:  function to_date(double precision, unknown) does not exist
LINE 12:             ||'day'||to_char( to_date(trunc(((to_date(TO_CHAR...
                                      ^
HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
Does anyone help me?
```

Comment: Those gazzillions of nested `to_date()` and `to_char()` calls look very strange. What is the _actual_ problem you are trying to solve with that? I'm pretty sure there is a much better way to do that. Are you maybe looking for a simple `transition_time - enter_time` or something similar?

Answer (score 0):

`trunc` returns a double.

Use a CAST to integer instead of `trunc`, i.e. replace `trunc(x)` with `CAST(x AS integer)`

Your query is *bizarre* though. Why are you doing this?:

```
to_date(TO_CHAR(l.transition_time , 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss'),'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss')
```

It's a meaningless no-op. What are you trying to achieve? There's so much needless complexity there I'd have to go through and simplify it out to understand what final value it's trying to produce. I suspect it can be done *much* more easily with `format(...)`, `to_char(...)` and interval operators.